# Count values in xslt array

Tags: xslt

I have this below XSLT.

and I want to check count of a particular element in an array.

Example:- Here I want to check the count of `A` in an  array.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="input-as-map" select="parse-json($input)" as="map(*)"/>
        <root>
            
            <!-- storing all the PERSONNUMBER present in the ibop -->
            <xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">
               
                    <Item>A</Item>
                    <Item>A</Item>
                    <Item>A</Item>
                    <Item>b</Item>              
            </xsl:variable>
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="count($array/Item='A')"/>
            </test>            
        </root>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions would also be helpful........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your declaration `<xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">` you have a sequence of element nodes, *not* an array. And you want `count($array[. = 'A'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="array">
  <Item>A</Item>
  <Item>A</Item>
  <Item>A</Item>
  <Item>b</Item>              
</xsl:variable>
<test>
  <xsl:value-of select="count($array/Item[.='A'])"/>
</test>
```